# Which is the Assembler which supports most of the existing interrupts?

Tags: x86-16

I Am currently using emu8086(so i am programming for the 8086mP) but i have a hard time with emu8086 since it cannot "understand" interrupts like int 21h/ah=5bh and many others.What assembler/ide should i use to be able to use other interrupts?(Emu8086 doesnt even support the interrupts which it should,not to mention,the ones added later)

Comment: Interrupt service routines are not feature of the processor, nor any assembler. They are provided by the BIOS and the operating system and no assembler on earth has anything to do with them. The `int` mnemonic, on the other hand (translating into `0CDh` except for `int 3`), is supported by virtually everything. That summarized, you question does not really make sense. Espcially when it comes to confusion between assemblers and emulators. For `int 21h`, install DOS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "support interrupts".  If the issue is to have so-called opcodes for various machine traps or OS calls via traps, the easiest thing to do is to defined parameterized macros for each such trap, and then simply invoke the appropriate macro.

So "int21/ah=5bh" might represent an OS call to "OutputCharacterAL".  You'd define a macro:

```
OutputCharacterAL  macro
          mov  ah,5bh
          int21
          mend
```

and invoke it by

```
         mov AL,"*"
         OutputCharacterAL
```

Virtually any assembler will let you do this, so there isn't any "best".

Comment: I'd rather define a runtime library for that

Comment: @Powerslave: You can do that, at a price.  The point of a trap is to provide isolation between the OS and the application.  If you insist on a subtroutine library, it means each "OS call" has extra overhead in the form of a subroutine call before it does a trap, or it means that the OS is not isolated from the application.   If you define a macro library, you can always make it generate a runtime library call, for those OS calls where OS overhead is not important, and the subroutine can do use user-space work that the OS side finds awkward to do.

Comment: Well, every OS does very much the same with RTL functions like `fork()` or `HeapAlloc()`, etc (except this two is OS-specific). The purpose actually is to isolate the application from the code stub that traps into the kernel. This provides a crude decoupling and a nice clean API. The point of the trap is not about isolating from the OS (even more, you are invoking OS-specific vectors, thus you're tighly coupled to it), but to provide means to invoke privileged code from userland. Also, besides the overhead of trapping into the kernel, the cost of a subroutine call is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The few times I need an x86 emulator I use [this](http://pcemu.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out NGASM, 
ref: http://www.bestdiskrecovery.com/ngasm/index.html